# How to find the curve of intersection of two surfaces?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, surfaces, curves

Let

$$
f(x,y,z)=y+x^{2}-z=0
$$
$$
g(x,y,z)=x^{3}+y^{2}-z=0
$$

How to find the curve of intersection of $f$ and $g$? Please don't work it out just tell me how to go about it?

Thanks.

Comment: The difference of both equations is a quadratic equation in $y$ (with coefficients that are functions of $x$).

Comment: @LutzL, So does the difference of both equations yield  the curve?

Comment: @LutzL, Do you mean that the equation of the curve is the solution of differences of the two equation i.e. $y=\frac{1}{2} \left(1\pm \sqrt{-4 x^3+4 x^2+1}\right)$.

Comment: Yes. You get $z$ from either of the equations if you have $x$ and $y$.

Answer (score 2):

I would look for a parametric equation $x=x(t)$, $y=y(t)$, $z=z(t)$. Since $z$ is by itself in both equations, I seems reasonable to choose $z(t)=t$. This leaves you with two equations in the unknowns $x,y$ to be solved in terms of $t$. This may lead to a nasty fourth order equation. After a little thought, it looks that choosing $x(t)=t$ will make things easier.